# i created image upload using php & xampp in android studio.but i don't know how to set upload limit in image file?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have created an image upload using php & xampp in Android Studio, but I don't know how to set upload limit in image file?

[image]

My code is,

```
package com.moqawalat.uploadimg;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.CameraPhoto;
import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.GalleryPhoto;
import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageBase64;
import com.kosalgeek.android.photoutil.ImageLoader;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.EachExceptionsHandler;
import com.kosalgeek.genasync12.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();

    ImageView ivCamera,ivGallery,ivUpload,ivImage;
    private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMG = 1;

    CameraPhoto cameraPhoto;
    GalleryPhoto galleryPhoto;
    String selectedPhoto;

    final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 13323;
    final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 22131;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cameraPhoto = new CameraPhoto(getApplicationContext());
        galleryPhoto = new GalleryPhoto(getApplicationContext());

        ivCamera = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivCamera);
        ivGallery = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivGallery);
        ivUpload = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivUpload);
        ivImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivImage);


        ivCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                try{
                    startActivityForResult(cameraPhoto.takePhotoIntent(), CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    cameraPhoto.addToGallery();
                }catch (IOException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

        ivGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                startActivityForResult(galleryPhoto.openGalleryIntent(), GALLERY_REQUEST);

            }
        });

        ivUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {


                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(selectedPhoto).requestSize(1024, 1024).getBitmap();
                    String encodedImage = ImageBase64.encode(bitmap);
                    Log.d(TAG, encodedImage);

                    HashMap<String, String> postData = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    postData.put("image", encodedImage);

                    PostResponseAsyncTask  task = new PostResponseAsyncTask(MainActivity.this, postData, new AsyncResponse() {


                        @Override
                        public void processFinish(String s) {



                            if(s.contains("uploaded_success")){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Image Uploaded Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                            else{
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error while uploading...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }

                        }
                    });
                    task.execute("http://192.168.1.7/news/upload.php");
                    task.setEachExceptionsHandler(new EachExceptionsHandler() {
                        @Override
                        public void handleIOException(IOException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cannot Connect to Server.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "URL Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleProtocolException(ProtocolException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Protocol Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void handleUnsupportedEncodingException(UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unsupported Error.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){


        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if(requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST){
                String photoPath = cameraPhoto.getPhotoPath();
                selectedPhoto = photoPath;
                Bitmap bitmap = null;
                try {
                     bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something wrong while taking photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else if(requestCode == GALLERY_REQUEST) {

                Uri uri = data.getData();
                galleryPhoto.setPhotoUri(uri);

                String photoPath = galleryPhoto.getPath();
                selectedPhoto = photoPath;
                try{
                    Bitmap bitmap = ImageLoader.init().from(photoPath).requestSize(512, 512).getBitmap();
                    ivImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Something wrong while choosing photos", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }

    }


}


php file :

<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['image'])){
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $id  = $now->format('YmdHisu');

    $upload_folder = "upload/";
    $path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpg";
    $image = $_POST['image'];


    if(file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image)) != false){
        echo "uploaded_success";
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "upload_failed";
    exit;
    }
    }
    else{

    echo "image_not_in";
    exit;


}
?>

activity_main :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.moqawalat.uploadimg.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="39dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="39dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
        android:id="@+id/ivGallery"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera"

        android:id="@+id/ivCamera"
        android:layout_marginLeft="11dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivGallery"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_upload_you_tube"
        android:id="@+id/ivUpload"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/ivGallery"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_below="@+id/ivGallery"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="161dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I am a newbie in Android, and I don't know how to set the upload size limit in uploading image. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
if(isset($_POST['image']['size'] < 5242880)){
    $now = DateTime::createFromFormat('U.u', microtime(true));
    $id  = $now->format('YmdHisu');

    $upload_folder = "upload/";
    $path = "$upload_folder/$id.jpg";
    $image = $_POST['image'];


    if(file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($image)) != false){
        echo "uploaded_success";
        exit;
    }
    else 
    {
    echo "upload_failed";
    exit;
    }
    }
    else{

    echo "image_not_in";
    exit;


}
?>
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27009716/php-file-upload-max-size-of-image-specification)

**you want set limit to your file in php code to upload webserver you just use above code.it working perfectly.i checked it.**